# How to maintain usersessions in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, authentication, oauth-2.0

So I'm busy with a Spring Boot REST server which connects to a PostgreSQL database.

My goal is to make an application which can easiliy be ported to android that is able to send a login JSON POST request and then maintain a session so that you don't require to send the credentials again for other GET requests. What are some ways that I could implement something like this?

I'm a bit confused as to what to use. Because there are so many library's, I also heard about a Spring Sessions library and Auth2. Auth2 however seems to be more applicable for integration with facebook/google login, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add spring-security to that spring boot in order to handle and maintain sessions. Take a look into their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-security.html) and view this [blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session) to help you out. You will have some reading fun time, yeah!